# Use mod_jk without Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

Is it possible to use mod_jk as reverse proxy without installing Tomcat?
I have Apache and JBoss installed, I don't see why I should install Tomcat?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod_jk` just speaks a particular protocol (`AJP13` to be specific). It's not bound to Tomcat in any way. Sure, you can use it with other products.

Spoiler alert: JBoss uses Tomcat as it's servlet container internally.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the combination mod_jk(Load balancer), JBoss(Application server) and Apache (Webserver). Mod_jk is just for communinication using the protocol AJP13 / AJP12.

Default port for AJP 13 is 8009.
Mod_JK 1.2.46, JBoss 7.1.0 GA and Apache 2.4.6 version combination is working perfectly for me.